# Dynamically changing an order number to end in _ERR

Tags: sql-server, update

I'm trying to update multiple orders at once instead of doing them one at a time. Is there a way to dynamically update them all at once?

For example: I have 5 orders ABC, BCD, CDE, DEF, EFG.

I need to update them to look like this ABC_ERR, BCD_ERR, CDE_ERR, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be a different concatenation operator depending on the RDMS you're using. For instance:

- Oracle uses `||`
- SQL Server uses `+`
- MySQL uses `concat`

...but everything else looks like:

```
UPDATE table1 SET order = order ||'_ERR' WHERE [your condition]
```

Since the question is tagged for SQL Server, the applicable syntax is:

```
UPDATE table1 SET order = order +'_ERR' WHERE [your condition]
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use SQL Server String Concatenation.

```
UPDATE YourTableName
SET ColumnName = ColumnName+'_ERR'
WHERE CoumnID<1 --- Apply filter if any required in your case
```